# Как через регулярные выражения узнать, есть ли слово, а потом разобрать на составляющие?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть строчка такого типа:

*"юр. пансионат солнышко 77"*

его состав: юр. - название компании - регион.

Мне нужно узнать, содержит ли строчка слово "юр.", и если содержит - достать в две переменные: название компании и его регион.
Я действую сейчас так:

```
$inMsg = "юр. пансионат солнышко 77";
$inMsgEx = explode(' ', $inMsg); // рублю на массив
  if ($inMsgEx[0] == "юр.") { // проверяю первый элемент
    $reqRegion = array_pop($inMsgEx); // достаю последний
    array_shift($inMsgEx); // обрубаю начало
    $reqName = implode(' ', $inMsgEx); // собираю в кучу
  } // перфекционист плачет...
```

оно работает, но это костыль. мне не нравится эта дичь с разбором строки на массив, а потом сбором его обратно.
помогите пожалуйста с регуляркой. мысль такая:

```
если (регулярное выражение на наличие "юр.") {
регулярное выражение, которое достаёт всё, что после "юр." в одну переменную, 
а последнее число - в другую
}
```

Comment: `preg_match_all('|^([А-я]{2}\.)\s([A-zА-я\s]*)\s(\d*)|iu', 'юр. пансионат солнышко 77', $out); if ( !empty($out[0]) ) { $name = $out[2][0]; $region = $out[3][0]; }`

Comment: Если хотите чтоб выглядело не костыльно, не стройте условий для костылей. Ваш "юр" сам по себе костыль в коде. Если хотите разделить логику на части советую строить парсер который будет возращять вам нужный объект

Comment: @AzizUmarov, непонятно откуда и как берётся строка для разбивки. В идеале тут, наверное, нужно бд доработать\переработать.

Comment: В идеале у вас не должно созникать подобных задач.

Comment: И вы всё храните как нужно, так что не возникают подобные проблемы

Comment: В данной ситуации вы просто один раз пробегаетесь по названиям и правите значения. Да это нудно и противно но такова цена

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = 'юр.  пансионат солнышко 77';

$re1 = '~^(юр\.)~iU';

if (preg_match($re1, $str, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, 0)) {

    $re23 = '~^(юр\.)([\S\s]+)([0-9]+$)~iU';      //выдираем между юр. и последни числом
                                                  //$re23 - шаг 2 и 3 в одном, потому и имя переменной такое
    $subst = '$2';
    $n_name = preg_replace($re23, $subst, $str, 1);
    $n_name = trim($n_name);

    echo "организац: " . $n_name;

    $subst = '$3';                              //регулярка та же, но тут посл число "выдираем"
    $n_numb = preg_replace($re23, $subst, $str, 1);
    
    echo "<br><br>номер: " . $n_numb;
}
```

*Наверное меня заминусуют?  Я давно с регекспами не работал*

---

А вообще-то было бы правильней(?) доработать\переработать бд, чтобы чуток разделить (дэ\нормализовать или дэ\нормализировать) хранение данных. Хотя возможно вы именно этим и занимаетесь (или вам только для вывода нужно такое разбиение)?

---

Я проверил у себя, но гарантий на работу кода не могу дать. Вдруг в таблице будет нечто неожиданное.

Comment: кажись я протупил. вам нужно ВСЕ что после ЮР. (в т ч и номер?) и еще раз номер, но отдельно? Думаю вы сами сможете это сделать. Нужно заменить     $subst = '$2'; на   $subst = '$2$3'; Этот комент я пишу не себе,  а автору вопроса.